# How do I make a LazyFrame with 4 billion rows?

Tags: python-polars

I'd like to make a `LazyFrame` where there is one column `'values'`, and elements go from `0` to `4_000_000_000`.

I'd tried

```
pl.LazyFrame({'values': pl.arange(0, 4_000_000_000, eager=True)})
```

but I get `Killed`.

`eager=False` gives me something else:

```py
In [1]: pl.LazyFrame({'values': pl.arange(0, 10, eager=False)}).collect()
Out[1]:
shape: (1, 1)
┌──────────────────────────┐
│ values                   │
│ ---                      │
│ object                   │
╞══════════════════════════╡
│ 0.([10]).alias("arange") │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `eager=True` and `eager=False` is that the former returns a Series while the latter returns an Expression. If you're already in a `select` or `with_columns` context then the distinction doesn't matter. If you're initiating a new Frame then you can't do so with an Expression. This is why the output you got has values as an object since an expression isn't a valid dtype.

What you can do is...

```
df=pl.LazyFrame().with_columns(values=pl.arange(0,4_000_000_000, eager=False))
```